# Enumerating battery devices c++ windows

Tags: c++, winapi, battery

I am using windows api to get various hardware info such as cpu usage and battery info.  I have been trying to get the names of the names of the battery devices by following this guide http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb204769%28v=vs.85%29.aspx but i am stuck when i get to here.

```
#define INITGUID
#include<windows.h>
#include<batclass.h>
#include<setupapi.h>
#include<devguid.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
HDEVINFO hdev = SetupDiGetClassDevs(&GUID_DEVCLASS_BATTERY, 0, 0, DIGCF_PRESENT 
| DIGCF_DEVICEINTERFACE);
}
```

but i am getting the following error

```
[Linker error] C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Temp\ccTMeaf9.o:Untitled1.cpp:(.text+0x28): undefined reference to `__imp_SetupDiGetClassDevsA' collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

i am a beginner in c++ so i might be missing something obvious but this is how they do it in the guide.  Any advice would be great.

Answer (score 3):

The documentation lied, that GUID is actually defined in devguid.h. Also (if you're not already doing this in another source file) you need to

```
#define INITGUID
```

before including BatClass.h and devguid.h. You'll get an undefined symbol error at link time if you don't have this once in your project, and a multiple-defined symbol error at link time if you have more than one.

Comment: ok got that and edited post accoedingly but now i am getting a new error

Comment: Are you linking against setupapi.lib? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff551069.aspx

Comment: i tried and got g++.exe g++.exe C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\g++.exe setupapi.lib: No such file or directory.

Answer (score 0):

It's defined in `devguid.h` in my mingw/GCC headers and my old copy of MSSDK.

Try adding this:

```
#include <devguid.h>
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code compiles here, on DevCPP:

```
#define INITGUID
#include <windows.h>
#include<ddk\batclass.h>
#include<setupapi.h>

int main() {
{
    HDEVINFO hdev = SetupDiGetClassDevs(&GUID_DEVICE_BATTERY, 0, 0, DIGCF_PRESENT | DIGCF_DEVICEINTERFACE);
}
```

Note **GUID_DEVICE_BATTERY**.

In order to get proper linking, you have to add to the project options|Parameters|Linker the library libsetupapi.a

The program is not tested to run. It only compiles properly.

Comment: i got g++.exe g++.exe C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\g++.exe setupapi.a: No such file or directory.

Comment: I don't know how you have to set the linker from the command line. In my DevCpp IDE installation, mentioned library is located in "c:/DevCpp/lib/libsetupapi.a" and you have to make project and to set project options as described in my answer above to link with this library.